# Bind context menu in resources ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my resources, I have created a Context menu and I want to bind it's `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection<object>` property called `ContextMenuItems` that I've created in my `xaml.cs` that is filled with items that I use to represent menu items. Currently, it looks like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu"
             DataContext="{Binding}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}">
       <ContextMenu.Resources>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CtContextMenuItem}">
                   <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}"
                          Click="MenuItem_OnClick"
                          Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CtContextMenuSepparatorItem}">
               <Separator />
           </DataTemplate>
       </ContextMenu.Resources>
   </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then in my treview

```
<TreeView ContextMenu="{DynamicResource = ContextMenu}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomizableTreeBaseItem}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding TreeChildren}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" 
                     ContextMenu="{DynamicResource = ContextMenu}/>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

`TreeChildren` is a public Property on the `local:CustomizableTreeBaseItem` that contains public properties that are then bound to the items of the tree-view. An Observable collection of `local:CustomizableTreeBaseItem` is set as to the Items property of the tree-view from code-behind.

But this does not seem to work when I right-click items in my tree-view I don't get a context menu as I expect.
I have tried to look up if I need to create a resource that somehow is bound to the property but it does not seem like there is a way to that.
I have also tried to Bind the data context but I can't seem to come up with a path that would work.

Comment: Where is `TreeChildren` defined? How can we give you a path to it if we don't know where it is? Why did you put the `=` in `DynamicResource = ContextMenu`?

Comment: Setting `DataContext="{Binding}"` seems pointless. It would set the DataContext property to the value that it already has.

Comment: Sorry -- where is `ContextMenuItems` defined? Never mind `TreeChildren`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ContextMenuItems` property is defined in the code-behind of the `UserControl` where the `ContextMenu` resource is defined, you could specify a `RelativeSource`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        ...
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```